# django orm sort by foreign key occurence in another table

Tags: python, django, sqlite, orm, django-database

Suppose to have something like the following tables:

```
class Book(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    book = models.CharField(Book, db_column="book", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
```

and wanting to retrieve a queryset of books ordered by number of purchases (i.e. occurrences of the foreign key in the other table).

```
Book.objects.all().annotate(number_of_purchases=Count(**something**)).order_by('number_of_purchases')
```

Is this possible? I currently have no idea what the "something" should be replaced with.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with [**`.annotate(…)`** <sup>[Django-doc]</sup>](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/models/querysets/#annotate):

```
from django.db.models import Count

Book.objects.annotate(
    npurchase=Count('purchase')
).order_by('-npurchase')
```